# Testing vim plugin private functions

Tags: vim

I'm creating a vim plugin which has a couple of private functions and I'm trying to add unitary testing to it using [vim-vspec](https://github.com/kana/vim-vspec).

What is the best way to invoke these private functions in the test file?

For now, I created a public function that invokes the private one, but I don't think that's a good approach because I'm loosing the point of having a private function. Here's some of the code

```
" File foo.vim (the plugin)

" Private function 
fu! s:foo(arg)
...
endfu

" Public function
fu! InvokeFoo(arg)
   call <SID>foo(a:arg)
endfu
```

---

```
" File foo-unittest.vim (the test file)
runtime! plugin/foo.vim

describe 'foo function'

    it 'should have some behavior'
        call InvokeFoo(...)
        " Some expectations ...
    end
end
```

I tried creating maps to the private functions but when I call `exe map_combination` it doesn't have any effect on the testing buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/bUE3yaAQXRc), and it gives one approach for variables and another for functions.

### Variables

For the variables, I used vim's scopes. Calling :help internal-variables:

> The scope name by itself can be used as a Dictionary.  For example, to
>   delete all script-local variables:
>
> ```
>     :for k in keys(s:)
>     :    unlet s:[k]
>     :endfor
> ```

So I access the `:s` scope by making a getter function to its dictionary:

```
fun! SScope()
    return s:
endfu
```

And finally an variable `s:variable` will be accessed by:

```
let l:scope = SScope()
echom l:scope['variable']
```

### Functions

The functions are a bit more complicated due the `<SID>` string. If you read the manual you'll get

> When executing the map command, Vim will replace `<SID>` with the
>   special                                       key code , followed
>   by a number that's unique for the script, and an underscore.  Example:
>
> `:map <SID>Add` could define a mapping "23_Add".

So, we need to access this unique number and one way to do it is to define a map that will serve as an accesor using `maparg` inside a function:

```
fu! SID()
    return maparg('<SID>', 'n')
endfu

nnoremap <SID> <SID>
```

Then, to call the function we will make a little hack:

```
call call(substitute('s:my_function', '^s:', SID(), ''), [arg1, arg2, ...])
```